# Can i get path from url i give in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want the path name after i request a url i setting.

let say i put  http://www.abc.com

then the server will auto return me to http://www.abc.com/sessionId/folder/default.aspx

and i need to get the return url in jquery.

Got anyway to do this?

i try ajax get/post to get the response header location and it always get null value.

Is a Reference code i show at below

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/echo/html',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res,status,XHR) { 
        //var location = XHR..getResponseHeader('Location');
          alert(XHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
          alert(XHR.getResponseHeader('Location'));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR) { }
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 'http://www.abc.com/sessionId/folder/default.aspx',
    request = 'http://www.abc.com';

console.log(result.substring(request.length)); // /sessionId/folder/default.aspx
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/zNN4D/

Comment: Sir, I don't know, but you deserve an up vote. +1 for you sir

Answer (score 0):

You can use a location object for this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

To create one from a url:

```
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = "http://www.abc.com/sessionId/folder/default.aspx";
console.log(url.pathname); // this is what you need.
```

The link shows a lot more options, from protocol to hash, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://www.abc.com/sessionId/folder/default.aspx',
    cutting = 'http://www.abc.com';

console.log(url.replace(cutting,''));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zNN4D/1/)**

Also if you wish can follow the solution from @zerkms.

Comment: Curious why this answer got an upvote and mine didn't (though the same idea and this was 10 minutes after)